# Why does iTunes re-open after I quit the app?

Tags: macos, itunes

Whenever I quit iTunes, it restarts itself. I have iTunes 10.1.12 (the newest one) installed on my Mac.  I don't remember exactly when it started—with either version 10 or 10.1.

Is there any solution to this?

### ADDED

It was caused by the [GimmeSomeTune](http://www.eternalstorms.at/gimmesometune/GimmeSomeTune/GimmeSomeTune.html), after reinstalling it, everything seems to working fine.

Comment: It sounds like it's crashing when you close it (for whatever reason), and restarting because of the crash. You will probably have to fish through log files to see if that is the case.

Comment: True. Open Console.cpp and see if you can catch some logged error when the problem happen

Answer (score 1):

I used to have this problem when I had SRS iWow installed in iTunes. Is that the case for you?

If not, do you have any other plugins installed?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this problem with iTunes. No matter how many times I quit the app it kept launching again. I believe it has something to do with the headphone jack and the way earbuds with remote controls can play or stop music. It seems like the headphone signal gets stuck in play mode.

Unplugging the cord from my MacBook Pro's headphone jack and plugging it back in always solves the problem.