# iTunes keeps respawning

Tags: itunes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does iTunes re-open after I quit?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8161/why-does-itunes-re-open-after-i-quit)

Hey,

I have some rather annyoing behavior with my system:
Whenever I close or `kill -9`iTunes it just keeps coming back up.

Any ideas how I can find **the root cause** of this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use any add-ons / controllers for iTunes, like Media Servers (eg. Plex, Front Row) or others for global hot-keys or song notifications? Sometimes these apps use applescript, which tends to launch applications if they´re not already running.

Comment: Actually I do. I use Last.fm and the scrobbler starts with iTunes. I'll try deinstalling that.